# Magento 1.7 - Remove fields from registration in /customer/account/create/

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to remove fields from Registration (/customer/account/create/). How can I do this?
is there some way without get into files of the store (e.g. hiding these fields)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should update some fields in the DB.

For example. I need to remove last name from registration form. It's a requried field.
So I created own module with sql update file to change field parameters:

**upgrade-1.0.0.1-1.0.0.2.php**

```
/* @var $installer Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup */

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();
// SELECT attribute_id, entity_type_id FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'lastname'
// SELECT * FROM customer_eav_attribute where attribute_id in (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'lastname')
$options = unserialize('a:2:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:255;s:15:"min_text_length";i:1;}');

if (isset($options['min_text_length'])) unset($options['min_text_length']);

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'lastname', array(
    'validate_rules' => serialize($options),
    'required'       => false
));

$installer->addAttribute('customer_address', 'lastname', array(
    'validate_rules' => serialize($options),
    'required'       => false
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

After that you should hide this field using html+css or js

**UPDATE:**

Edit file */app/design/frontend/default/YOURTHEME/template/customer/widget/name.phtml* to change your registration form. In my case I commented out html block there:

```
<?php /*if ($this->showMiddlename()): ?>
        <?php $isMiddlenameRequired = $this->isMiddlenameRequired(); ?>
        <div class="field name-middlename">
            <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>"<?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? ' class="required"' : '' ?>><?php echo $isMiddlenameRequired ? '<em>*</em>' : '' ?><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('middlename')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('middlename')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getMiddlename()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('middlename') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('middlename') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; */?>

    <!--<div class="field name-lastname">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId('lastname')?>" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName('lastname')?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getObject()->getLastname()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getStoreLabel('lastname') ?>" maxlength="255" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('lastname') ?>" <?php echo $this->getFieldParams() ?> />
        </div>
    </div>-->
```

Also you could add some class to `<div class="field name-middlename">` and `<div class="field name-lastname">`. This class should has css property `"display:none;"`.

Comment: Thanks! And how it would be the part of html+css?

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I got it to work. This is want I did and I request you to try it and check if it solves the issue.

1. Open Magento DB and go to the table core_config_data.
2. Search for the path - `customer/address/middlename_show`.
3. Edit Value field for `customer/address/middlename_show` and change it to **1** . Generally, this will be 0 (zero) by default.
4. Save the table.
5. Clear Cache. Preferably delete the folder Cache and Session present in var folder.
6. Login to Magento admin and go to the following location:
   **System --> Configuration --> CUSTOMERS --> Customer Configuration**
7. Under "Name and Address Options" tab, now the option for "Show Middle Name (initial)" will be shown as "Yes".
8. Change it to "No".
9. Save Config and clear Cache.